# Undefined variable when integrating PHPExcel with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to OOP and also CodeIgniter. Started a day ago with the basic example of Pages Controller and pages. Now I need to integrate with PHPExcel. Here is my controller:

```
<?php

class Report extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function readReport() {
        $file = APPPATH."/third_party/teste.xlsx";
        //load the excel library
        $this->load->library('excel');
        //read file from path
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
        //get only the Cell Collection
        $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
        //extract to a PHP readable array format
        foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
            $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
            $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
            $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
            //header will/should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
            if ($row == 1) {
                $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            } else {
                $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            }
        }
        //send the data in an array format
        $data['teste'] = "Rodrigo";
        $data['header'] = $header;
        $data['values'] = $arr_data;
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
        }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <?php echo $teste; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

Pages Controller:

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    public function view ($page = 'home') {
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = str_replace("_", " ", $page);

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: teste

Filename: pages/home.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\application\views\pages\home.php
Line: 6
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 13
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Can someone help what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Need to add `$data['teste'] = "Rodrigo";` in Pages Controller too

Comment: @Saty ok thats working with "Rodrigo" in Pages, but actually I've done that just for test, I need to send $data['header'] = $header; and $data['values'] = $arr_data; that is of PHPExcel, if I try to send that to Pages, the variable isn't exists because it's in the Report controller.

Comment: @RodrigoBRF you must have to add `$data['header']` and `$data['values']` to your pages controller.

Comment: @Ranjith yes, I have done that. But, when I did that, the message in NetBeans is that "$arr_data" doesn't exist. Yes, because it is in Report Controller. :(

Answer (score 1):

In pages controller you don't have $data['teste'] variable. From pages controller only you are accessing the variable.

Comment: As @saty commented.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I replied at Saty comment the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't declared `teste` variable in your Pages Controller you need to declare it as @Saty mentioned in comment or you need to use `isset` before it print in your view file as below

```
<?php if(isset($teste)) {
        echo $teste; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I replied at Saty comment the problem now.